Are there approximability schemes for NP-Hard problems using quantum algorithms?
I'm looking into some parts of Quantum Complexity Theory and was wondering if we have any approximability schemes for NP-Hard problems using quantum algorithms.
I was unable to find any literature on it after an hour of searching, perhaps my prompt engineering is just not there yet.
In other words, do we have a quantum equivalent for FPTAS, PTAS and APX?
At least from my understanding, assuming you can get a superexponential speedup on an approximation for a problem (it is not obvious such a speedup exists, to my knowledge), then quantum computers can approximate 'better' and would have to be classed differentely.
As another question of further interest on the topic, has there been any attempt to extend (qoute Wikipedia):
"Any strongly NP-hard optimization problem with a polynomially bounded objective function cannot have an FPTAS unless P=NP."
to the quantum domain?
Just some ideas I would like to know if anyone has worked on them and if there is any literature on it.

Have you explored the Complexity Zoo?

@MarkSpinelli I have explored the complexity zoo quite a alot and never found anything regarding what I am searching for.
